# Illustrator: Option to deselect "Transform Objects" and select "Transform Patterns greyed out"

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am running Illustrator CC 2019.

[image: Picture of my issue].

Comment: It's really difficult to help with merely a screen shot. Especially one which does not show the Layers or Appearance panels.

Answer (score 1):

While the selected object has a flat lilac color as it is shown in both: the Swatches panel and the Tool palette, you can not choose between transforming the object or the pattern fill because there is only the option to transform the object.

[image]

You are selecting an object that doesn't correspond to one with pattern filling. Maybe a Clipping Mask frame.